# Is highcharts sparkline with multiple series possible?

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to have multiple series/datapoints per sparkline chart in a sparkline set? The demo page for the sparkline page doesnt show any form of customization other than physical appearance like color.

Comment: Sparkline is a just a set of charts inside a table - you can customise it as you customise a regular chart. If you want multiple series inside the chart, set it in series prop - http://jsfiddle.net/6pvzb2zc/

Comment: thanks mate! this is just the answer that i needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just copy/pasting morganfree's answer so I can mark this question as answered already. cheers~

> Sparkline is a just a set of charts inside a table - you can customise
>   it as you customise a regular chart. If you want multiple series
>   inside the chart, set it in series prop - jsfiddle.net/6pvzb2zc –
>   morganfree